# JPA - How to call method for web service after commit

Tags: java, jpa

Sorry for something that is probably very simple, but I'm new to JPA and I'm not sure where to insert a function call for a method that needs to be called **after** a new record is committed to a database.  I have the following:

```
@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
@Path("...")
@RolesAllowed("...")
public void create(LearningActivity entity){
    super.create(entity);
}
```

I need to call a custom method myMethod() after the above process is completed.  I thought I could add it immediately after super.create(entity) but apparently the commit process isn't completed until the whole create() method executes.  I've also tried adding @PostPersist to the underlying entity but that's still before the record is committed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure where to insert a function call for a method that needs
>   to be called after a new record is committed to a database

It sound like you need to use Event Listener, there is an event called PostPersist that is executed every time a entity has been commited to the database, you can configure that using the above code.

```
@Entity
public class X{
  @PostPersist
  public void myMethod(){
    //Do anything before the commit of the transaction that save a new entity of type X 
  }

 @PostUpdate
 public void myMethod2(){
  //This code will run each time you update and save an entity of type X
 }
}
```

PostPersist is called after the commit has been completed, PrePersist executes when you call persist method.

Comment: Koitoer,  Thank you.  I've actually tried the PostPersist at the entity level as you suggested.  There seems to be some confusion in the documentation for this.  The general description given is that it executes "after storing a new entity in the database (during commit or flush)."  Using the debugger I was able to determine that PostPersist appears to execute after the data is persisted to the JPA object, but **before** the commit to the DB.  I need to test this some more, but I'm about to toss JPA and go back to JDBC.

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to add a custom event listener similar to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm#i1000654

Comment: The j2ee event listener servlet and filter are not related to the JPA, obviously you could ad a filter to make any process in the database at the end of the transaction but that not sound a good design about it, but who cares XD, I suggest better use a Service layer with Transactional annotation.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.  Can you point me to an example of a service layer with Transactional annotation?  I would appreciate it as I'm still pretty overwhelmed by all of this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this article](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/entity-listeners.html), `@PostPersist` is called **before** commit.

The alternative that I found is to create a static helper method that will call a `Runnable` after current transaction session is committed.

```java
  public static void afterTransactionCommitted(final Runnable function) {
    if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive()) {
      TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(
        new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
          @Override
          public void afterCommit() {
            function.run();
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      function.run();
    }
  }
```

You will use it like

```
afterTransactionCommitted(() -> myMethod());
```